# Add Kafka to project on Heroku

Tags: heroku, apache-kafka

Is there any detailed instruction about adding Kafka  to a backend Spring Boot project on Heroku?

Despite opening for running Kafka on local, and running host server on Heroku, the "log" in Heroku says that `WARN 4 --- [ntainer#1-0-C-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Consumer clientId=consumer-backend-service-12, groupId=backend-service] Bootstrap broker localhost:9092 (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected`.

I also tried install Kafka add-on method, but it says `Uncaught exception in thread 'kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1':`.

The demo github provided in documentation does not work for me, when there are some packages that spring boot does not recognize.

Comment: Read the documentation? https://www.heroku.com/kafka

Comment: I've edited your question to exclude Redis since it's unrelated to the error you've posted. Posts should ask one question. Create another post (or, still, search Heroku for managed Redis) instead

Answer (score 0):

Unclear what demo you're referring to, or "add on".

Your error says your app cannot connect to itself on port 9092. Your app probably isn't a Kafka broker, and therefore needs to use an external IP/hostname where a broker actually is running.

Perhaps the demo was requiring you to run Kafka on your own machine, rather than in Heroku. I personally don't use Heroku, but your error is not related to it. Regarding Spring, if you picked Spring Kafka via start.spring.io, then yes, that defaults to a localhost connection